# Getting value from product attributes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

I have custom attributes for my products. Some attributes are in text format and some are in select list. I want to print those attributes in my template. 
Here is code I am using: 
`

```
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
$attrSetID = $_product->getAttributeSetId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$sql = "select attribute_group_id from eav_attribute_group where attribute_group_name = 'Additional Attributes'  AND attribute_set_id=$attrSetID";
$data = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
$groupId = array_pop($data);
if ($groupId && $attributes) {
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->isInGroup($attrSetID, $groupId['attribute_group_id'])) {
            if ($attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) == 'No') {
                $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
//              $atest = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
//              $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
            } else {
                echo  $attribute->getFrontendLabel() . ' : ' . $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }                            
}
```

And my problem is that Magento print only attributes which are not select type. For attributes that are select type Magento print "No".

I tried to print selected value of attribute like this, but output is still "No".

1. $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrCode)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
2. $_product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute_code')

In google I found only couple solutions for Magento 1x, so if someone can help me, i would appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that $_product object was not getting all attributes. So I add ->addAttributeToSelect(array('*')) in function that get attributes from database and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have assigned "your attribute" to appropriate Attribute Set.

Also, select your attribute for the product as well.

You can get attribute text by using below code.

```
echo $_product->getAttributeText('your attribute');
```

if `$_product` doesn't work for you then try below code to get product data.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

OR

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
```

Hope it works and help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't help. 
I tried to get product as you said and it even didn't return product.
Here is my $this and $block object.
$this - Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php
$block  -  Sm\ListingTabs\Block\ListingTabs\Interceptor

As I mention before $_product->getAttributeText('your attribute') is not working for me.

Comment: I forgot to mention, i get attribute value for product where  attribute type is text. It only doesn't work when attribute is select type.